# How to change the output directory of a project in the solution file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Without writing a Cmake file is there any way of modifying the properties of the solution file, so that  all the projects that get added to this solution file will have the output directory as `$(ProjectDir)$(ConfigurationName)`

Comment: Do you mean using the Visual Studio development environment, or pragmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe can be done with Property Sheets in Visual Studio. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z7t21ew%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: +1 I just now saw the question asked for newly *added* projects, and yes, a prop-sheet will help considerably with this.